Azure Devops- Getting Error code: InvalidDeploymentParameterKey
I am trying to deploy basic infrastrture for mlops using arm template
but getting below error
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidDeploymentParameterKey.
##[error]One of the deployment parameters has an empty key.

i have a variable group -  mlops_infra_variable_grp and none of keys is empty
Below is the arm template used for the deployment
template - iac-create-environment-pipeline-arm.yml
pr: none
trigger: none

variables:
- group: mlops_infra_variable_grp

stages:
- stage: 'Dev'
  displayName: 'Dev'
  jobs:
  - job: "Provision_Dev"
    displayName: "Provision Dev resources"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_SERVICE_CON)'
        action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
        resourceGroupName: '$(RESOURCE_GROUP)'
        location: $(LOCATION)
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment_setup/cloud-environment.json'
        overrideParameters: '-baseName $(BASE_NAME) -location $(LOCATION) -workspace $(WORKSPACE_NAME)'
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      displayName: 'Deploy OH resources to Azure'


What causing the error?

Hi @hari-azure, welcome to SO :-) The error message is clear, one of the parameters doesn't seem to be set. Maybe try adding a dummy task before AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2 where you just write the parameters values? This way you should be able to quickly find out which one is missing.

HI @RuiJarimba , parameters / variable values are printing as tested but not understanding the issue ?

@hari-azure I was suggesting to print the variables to ensure all variables have values.

@RuiJarimba yes as suggested , i print the variables, but still getting the same error even all variable  value are printing

Try to deploy using Azure CLI command az deployment group create on your local machine and check if there is the same error. Replace { } with your actual value.
templateFile="{provide-the-path-to-the-template-file}"
az deployment group create \
  --resource-group {yourResourceGroup} \
  --template-file $templateFile \
  --parameters baseName={ } location={ } workspace={ }

If there is the same error, check if there is anything wrong in your template. If it works locally, the issue may be related to the pipeline settings. You can try to run the same commands in AzureCLI@2 - Azure CLI v2 task and check what's the result.


There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidDeploymentParameterKey.

The cause of the issue could be that the value of the ARM Parameter contains special characters(e.g. space).
To solve this issue, you can add " "to the parameters value. For example: -baseName "$(BASE_NAME)"
Task sample:
variables:
- group: mlops_infra_variable_grp

stages:
- stage: 'Dev'
  displayName: 'Dev'
  jobs:
  - job: "Provision_Dev"
    displayName: "Provision Dev resources"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(AZURE_SERVICE_CON)'
        action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
        resourceGroupName: '$(RESOURCE_GROUP)'
        location: $(LOCATION)
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment_setup/cloud-environment.json'
        overrideParameters: -baseName "$(BASE_NAME)" -location "$(LOCATION)" -workspace "$(WORKSPACE_NAME)"
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      displayName: 'Deploy OH resources to Azure'

